# docker-toolbox cannot access nginx server

Tags: windows-7, docker

After installing docker-toolbox on Windows 7 I followed the [Get Started, Part 2](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/). However, when trying to access the server e.g. via the browser I get no response. As if the server was not running. Same for e.g. a downloaded image for nginx (see below).

Commands used:

```
> docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=<proxy_host>:<proxy_port> --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy_host>:<proxy_port> --tag=friendlyhello .

> docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
friendlyhello       latest              652aa06a8b38        About an hour ago   131MB

> docker run -d -p 4000:80 friendlyhello

> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
ae26a10e9e1f        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:4000->80/tcp   lucid_albattani
```

Access in browser: localhost:4000 or the "local ip-adress":4000 (`docker-machine ip` gives me `Error getting IP address: Host is not running`).

Same result/problem for

```
> docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx               latest              881bd08c0b08        3 weeks ago         109MB

> docker run --name my-nginx81 -d -p 8081:80 nginx

> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
aaad65752f02        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   my-nginx81
```

Access in browser: localhost:8081 ir the "local ip-adress":8081

Answer (score 0):

Eh, after restarting the pc I found the solution. After startup I needed to execute again "Docker Quickstart Terminal" (as admin). After the execution (start.sh) in the window I got the message `Docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 12.34.56.78`. Using *that* ip-adress along with the ports (4000 or 8081) it worked :o